# Google spreasheet filter by string array

Tags: filter, google-sheets, substring

I want to create a filter view in my google spreadsheet which shows all rows where column C contains one of the values from a hard-coded set of values.

For example if I have a set like `Hotel1, Hotel2, Hotel3` then my filter view should show all rows which have Column C equal to one of these values like `Hotel2`. And if a row has column C = `Hotel4` it should be hidden.

Is it possible to create a filter view that returns true whenever the value of the given column is a substring of another string?

Comment: I found the answer to my question here..
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/88767

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, assuming the range to filter is several columns A to Z:

```
=filter(A:Z, match(C:C, {"Hotel1", "Hotel2"}, 0))
```

For your second question, same idea:

```
=filter(A:Z, regexmatch(C:C, "Hotel"))
```